# Open Contact Card Viewer/Editor from Outlook button

Tags: c#, button, callback, outlook, outlook-addin

I created a custom ribbon for Microsoft Outlook and I have a button called view profile. I want to be able to bring up the Contact Card Viewer/Editor for the current user. I created a call back and I think I have the general idea of how to get his done but I am having trouble making the connection once I find the current user to getting it to open for that user. Here is the code I have so far for the call back.

```
public void button2_Click(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
   var appOutlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
   Outlook.ExchangeUser currentUser = appOutlook.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser();
   ContactItem contactinfo = currentUser;
   contactinfo.ShowBusinessCardEditor();
}
```

[image: Custom Ribbon for Outlook]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ContactCard`.
Here is C# code converted from the VBA example on this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869218.aspx

```
        var session = appOutlook.Session;
        var adr = session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry;
        var cc = session.CreateContactCard(adr);
        cc.Show(MsoContactCardStyle.msoContactCardFull, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just calling the .Display(modal: true / false) method on the ContactItem.

```
ContactItem contact = ...
contact.Display(true); // for modal
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply call `AddressEntry.Details`:

```
Outlook.AddressEntry currentUser = appOutlook.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry;
currentUser.Details();
```